# Select multiple items in publishing queue and republish

Tags: publishing

Recently upgraded from Tridion 2011 to SDL Web8.
Found that - select multiple items in publishing queue and republish doesn't work, republishing from publishing queue works fine for single item.

The extension (Publish from Publishing Queue) available for 2013 SP1 is already installed but seems it is not working for multiple items.
Any ready references please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Git repo: [Publish from publishing queue](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Publish%20from%20Publishing%20Queue/trunk) ..

Get the latest source from this repo and use it. As per the comments on the latest commits, it was updated to work with web 8.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Hiren! It helped as the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the "**Tridion Content Manager Batch Processor**"? Try restarting the service.

It is usually the cause of malfunction when multiple operations are requested.

Comment: Hi Raul, checked this. Unfortunately didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that extension is compatible with SDL Web 8 - I've not had any luck with it.

You could always try installing Alchemy and using one of their plugins - https://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Republish

I suggest trying this on a non-production environment first to make sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Hiren above, this has now been fixed in the latest version of the **Publish from Publish Queue** code ([here](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Publish%20from%20Publishing%20Queue/trunk)).

Specifically, I had to update the following:

---

### Publish.js

Replaced this (approximately line 95):

```
tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishItems(
    items,
    instruction,
    PqPublish$_onMultiPublish$_onSendToQueue,
    PqPublish$_onMultiPublish$_onSendToQueueFailed
);
```

With this:

```
// 2013 & web 8 support
if (typeof tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.Publishing === "function") {
    tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishItems(
        items,
        instruction,
        PqPublish$_onMultiPublish$_onSendToQueue,
        PqPublish$_onMultiPublish$_onSendToQueueFailed
    );
} else {
    tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM.Publishing.PublishItems(
        items,
        instruction,
        PqPublish$_onMultiPublish$_onSendToQueue,
        PqPublish$_onMultiPublish$_onSendToQueueFailed
    );
}
```

---

### UnPublish.js

Replaced this (approximately line 70):

```
tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.Publishing.UnpublishItems(
    items,
    instruction,
    PqUnPublish$_onMultiUnpublish$_onSendToQueue,
    PqUnPublish$_onMultiUnpublish$_onSendToQueueFailed
);
```

With this:

```
// 2013 & web 8 support
if (typeof tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.Publishing === "function") {
    tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.Publishing.UnpublishItems(
        items,
        instruction,
        PqUnPublish$_onMultiUnpublish$_onSendToQueue,
        PqUnPublish$_onMultiUnpublish$_onSendToQueueFailed
    );
} else {
    tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM.Publishing.UnpublishItems(
        items,
        instruction,
        PqUnPublish$_onMultiUnpublish$_onSendToQueue,
        PqUnPublish$_onMultiUnpublish$_onSendToQueueFailed
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please restart all your tridion services and check the deployer targets is running properly..